# IIS8: Multiple Sites pointing to same physical folder, but each with different PHP version

Tags: php, iis

I am trying to configure IIS8 server on devel machine with multiple PHP versions (5.2, 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5) to test how scripts works against each version. On server level I successfully created all Handler mappings, created all 4 Sites (each for one PHP version) which all points to same physical path (**c:\www\htdocs**). Now I thought that for each site I will change Handler mapping order to make one PHP version primary. But problem is that this settings are saved to **web.config** file in **c:\www\htdocs**. So instead of changing PHP version for one site it changed for all sites.

Reading of [TechNet Documentation for web.config](http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/cc754617%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) does not helped a lot. Is this even possible to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the settings stored in the `applicationHost.config` server-level config file instead of in the `web.config` file in the folder.

One way to do this is to manually move the configuration from the `web.config` file into the `applicationHost.config` file, which is in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\`.

However, it is much safer not to edit this file by hand.  Instead you can use `appcmd set config SITE_NAME ...` with the `/commit:appHost` flag at the end (where ... is a setting to set).

To add PHP using AppCmd, you need to add a handler mapping in `system.webServer/handlers` and a FastCGI entry in `system.webServer/fastCGI`.  The [official PHP instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php#install.windows.iis7.fastcgi.conf.cmd) for IIS have the basic commands - all you need to do is add the site name after `set config` and the commit flag at the end.

Alternatively, you can use the IIS Manager's "Configuration Editor".  Microsoft's official tutorial for the Configuration editor is at http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/editing-collections-with-configuration-editor.